# Adjusting horizontal spacing for the \hat and \vec symbols relative to the argument of \vec,\hat

Tags: spacing

I've done some intrusive changes using the `unicode-math` package to still use a font of my liking, a font which is not supported by `TeX` out-of-the-box. Passing more options to `unicode-math` causes it to undefine more and more features, in comparison to just setting the math font and letting `unicode-math` do the work. That doesn't seem to be an option here, since I still want to use e.g. greek letters and so on, which are not directly supported by the font I want.

I'm now at a stage where I wish to use e.g. the `\vec` and `\hat` commands. To obtain the correct `unicode` range, I've used `\show\vec` and `\show\hat` in my document, from which I yielded the `unicode-math` related font command

```
\setmathfont[range={"020D7,"00302}]{XITS}
```

The resulting math expressions now look a little like this:

[image]

Needless to say, the result is not exactly as intended: both the `\vec` as well as the `\hat` command produce the incorrect horizontal alignment compared to their argument. Take for instance `\hat A`. The `\hat` is way too much to the left compared to the `A`. The same issue goes for the `\vec`'s at the top.

What options do I have to adjust this horizontal spacing "internally"? I've intentionally circumvented redefining `\vec` & `\hat` previously. Anyway, I know this issue is related to my font but it would be nice to have sort of a "universal" answer (if there is one), to just place these characters `5pt` to the right.

Here's an MWE to play with, with the same text as in the screenshot. Here I've imported the full `XITS` font for math purposes, which shows a similar issue: here, the `\hat` is aligned too far to the right compared to the `A` in the displaymath expression.

Lastly, solutions that are applicable to many cases are a pro, but are less than mandatory. If only `\hat` and `\vec` are covered in the solution I'm fine with that.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{XITS}

\begin{document}

In onze benadering stellen we dat er alleen een $\vec B$-veld is langs de $z$ as, waaruit een magnetisch veld volgt in de $z$-as van $\vec B_z=\left(\delta_xA_y-\delta_yA_x\right)\vec z$.

Omdat er eikenvariantie geldt, kunnen we al naar gelang bij onze elektrische potentiaal een scalar optellen zonder dat er iets verandert\. Daarom maken we de volgende substituties:
\begin{align}
\hat A&\rightarrow \hat A=\hat A+\nabla\psi\\
\phi&\rightarrow \phi=\phi-\frac1c\frac {\partial\psi}{\partial t}
\end{align}
Om hier echt iets mee te kunnen hebben we nog \'e\'en stap nodig. Normaal gesproken werken we in de Coulomb-eik met $\nabla\cdot\vec A=0$. We kunnen echter kiezen om in de Landau-eik te werken waarin geldt dat $\vec A=B\vec x\overline y$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps you'll be luckier with `\setmainfont{XITS Math}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use XITS Math, rather than XITS.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\begin{document}

In onze benadering stellen we dat er alleen een $\vec B$-veld 
is langs de $z$ as, waaruit een magnetisch veld volgt in de $z$-as van 
$\vec B_z=(\delta_xA_y-\delta_yA_x)\vec z$.

Omdat er eikenvariantie geldt, kunnen we al naar gelang bij onze 
elektrische potentiaal een scalar optellen zonder dat er iets verandert. 
Daarom maken we de volgende substituties:
\begin{align}
\hat A&\rightarrow \hat A=\hat A+\nabla\psi\\
\phi&\rightarrow \phi=\phi-\frac1c\frac {\partial\psi}{\partial t}
\end{align}
Om hier echt iets mee te kunnen hebben we nog \'e\'en stap nodig. 
Normaal gesproken werken we in de Coulomb-eik met $\nabla\cdot\vec A=0$. 
We kunnen echter kiezen om in de Landau-eik te werken waarin geldt dat 
$\vec A=B\vec x\overline y$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\setmathfont{XITS}` you get the warning

```
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "script-not-exist-latn"
* 
* Font 'XITS' does not contain script 'Math'.
* 'Latin' script used instead.
*************************************************
```

that should be self explanatory. Math fonts must contain special tables for setting the necessary parameters, for instance those regarding math accents.